# How to achieve a pure function with dynamic programming in Kotlin?

Tags: functional-programming, kotlin, tail-recursion

I've been trying to transform some of my code to pure functions to learn how to use Kotlin in a functional way, with this simple snippet of code I can't think of any way to make my `calculateFibonacci` function a pure function.

I'm aware of a potentially recursive solution but what about a potential stack overflow, does Kotlin implement Tail Call Optimization?

Example:

```
     val fibonacciValues = hashMapOf<Int, BigInteger>(0 to BigInteger.ONE, 1 to BigInteger.ONE);

 // * TODO investigate how to do dynamic programming with a pure function ** //
    private fun calculateFibonacci(n: Int): BigInteger? {
        if (fibonacciValues.contains(n)) {
            return fibonacciValues.get(n)
        } else {
            val f = calculateFibonacci(n - 2)!!.add(calculateFibonacci(n - 1))

            fibonacciValues.put(n, f)
            return f
        }
    }
```

For the whole snippet I uploaded this gist:
https://gist.github.com/moxi/e30f8e693bf044e8b6b80f8c05d4ac12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole thing is about breaking out of the imperative approach and thinking in terms of sequence manipulation.

In the case of the Fibonacci Sequence, it might be tricky because it's very tempting to think of it as a sequence of Ints but **it gets much easier if you think of it as a sequence of pairs** (from which you eventually derive a sequence of Ints)

So, you could create an infinite sequence of pairs where the next pair is defined as the second element of the previous pair and a sum of elements in a previous pair:

```
generateSequence(1 to 1) { it.second to it.first + it.second }
  .map { it.first }
```

---

And yes, you can utilize the Tail Call Optimization by marking your method with the `tailrec` keyword -  no worries about the stack overflow. You just apply it before the `fun` keyword:

```
fun fibonacciAt(n: Int) = {
    tailrec fun fibonacciAcc(n: Int, a: Long, b: Long): Long {
        return when (n == 0) {
            true -> b
            false -> fibonacciAcc(n - 1, a + b, a)
        }
    }

    fibonacciAcc(n, 1, 0)
}
```

Here is more info about the [Tail Recursion in Kotlin.](http://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-tail-recursion)

Answer (score 2):

Homegrown:

```
fun fib(i: Int): Int {
    tailrec fun go(k: Int, p: Int, c: Int): Int {
        return if (k == 0) p
        else go(k - 1, c, p + c)
    }

    return go(i, 0, 1)
}
```

[generateSequence](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/generate-sequence.html) actually shows a Fibonacci implementation as example.

```
fun fibonacci(): Sequence<Int> {
    // fibonacci terms
    // 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, ...
    return generateSequence(Pair(0, 1), { Pair(it.second, it.first + it.second) }).map { it.first }
}

println(fibonacci().take(10).toList()) // [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the main documentation

Answer (score 1):

> does Kotlin implements Tail Call Optimization

Yes, there is **tailrec** keyword for that.